# oracle and hive timestamp

Tags: oracle11g, hive, timestamp, hdfs

I have a vendor oracle DB storing values to a column `creation_timestamp` as `timestamp(6)` when i create an extract of that table and load it to HDFS and create hive schema with that column defined as `timestamp` it does not populate the field.  However if I use `string` it is all there.  I have other MSSQL `datetime` data that successfully stored as `timestamp` in hive so I am just a little unsure why the oracle `timestamp` data is not populating.

The oracle timestmap looks like this: `07-JAN-15 05.55.20.732754000 PM`
I have a feeling hive does not like the month as letters as the documentation states:`Strings: JDBC compliant java.sql.Timestamp format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.fffffffff" (9 decimal place precision)`

**How can I convert the oracle `timestamp(6)`:`07-JAN-15 05.55.20.732754000 PM` to the `java.sql.Timestamp format` shown above?**

Answer (score 1):

I was able to alter my session and then export the table, hive has now accepted it as a `timestamp`

`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF';`
`07-JAN-15 05.55.20.732754000 PM` is now: `2015-01-07 17:55:20.732754000`

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_date` in hive.

Example :

```
select TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('7-MAR-13', 'd-MMMM-yy'))) from table_name
```

Refer : [date functions](http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/date-functions-in-hive.html)

Comment: Give your format in place of 'd-MMM-yy' and try `cast(to_date(..) as timestamp)` that should do it.